# UICollectionView as a subView of a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, collections, html

I need an advice for a thing I want to implement for an iPhone application.

Actually what I want is to have the ability to dynamically populate a `TableView` with a specific template delivered by an engine (is it clear ? ...)

For that I want each of my `TableViewCell` of the `TableView` to be a `UICollectionView`.

For example :

I want to display an image, a title and a subtitle in my cell (I know I can do this by using a `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, but when I have more complicated things to display it won't work with it).

For that, I want a `UICollectionView` with 2 columns and 2 rows on each column. The first item (image) will be placed on 0,0 with a 2 colSpan (to take the whole column). The second item (title) on 1,0 and the third item (subtitle) on 1,1.
I also want the collection view items to be sized correctly.

So 2 questions :

1) Is it a good way to work with a `UICollectionView`, or is there simpler ways ?

2) How can I specify rows and columns, along with colspan and rowspan in a `UICollectionView` ?

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

A collection view is overkill for this. Just define a cell with custom subviews. You can resize them if required when the cell is populated. You haven't said what the most complex or simplest layout will be so I can't offer any more specific advice.

Comment: It's for any "design" we want, like if someone wants a text field, with an imageview, a datepicker, etc, I want that to be really customizable. Everything is done programmatically, an engine sends me controls and layouts for those controls in a Grid. Actually I want to "imitate" the WPF framework, don't know if you see what I mean ...

Comment: It's the Windows Presentation Foundation used to make windows GUI (and Windows Phone apps I think) -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/ms754130.aspx